# Declaring a variable of a class type and assigning it to a different variable in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here is the Objective-C code:

```
__weak classX *newVar = oldVar;
```

Which one of the following is the correct or the preferable way to achieve the same thing in Swift?

```
weak var newVar = classX()
newVar = self.oldVar
```

or

```
weak var newVar : classX() = oldVar
```

Comment: Would you show real example of what do you try to do? ... because your alternates might both be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want:

- If `oldVar` is of type `classX`, the following both are equivalent:

  ```
  weak var newVar = oldVar  // (1) type inferred
  weak var newVar:classX = oldVar // (2)
  ```

  It is a little matter of taste ([see discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271923/whats-the-tradeoff-for-type-inference/271940)) if you like type inference (1) or not.
- If the type of `oldVar` is a subtype of `classX`, then (2) comes closest, because it will not infer the concrete class of `oldVar` but limit it to `classX`

---

Btw., your first approach:

```
weak var newVar = classX()
newVar = self.oldVar
```

will lead to a compiler warning, because the first assignment (`newVar = classX()`) will create a new instance of `classX` and throw it immediately away because of the *weak*-ness of `newVar`